# Why is sin6_family needed on an IPv6 address?

Tags: c, unix

From the `man 7 ipv6`, we can see that an IPv6 address is internally represented like this:

```
struct sockaddr_in6 {
       sa_family_t     sin6_family;   /* AF_INET6 */
       in_port_t       sin6_port;     /* port number */
       uint32_t        sin6_flowinfo; /* IPv6 flow information */
       struct in6_addr sin6_addr;     /* IPv6 address */
       uint32_t        sin6_scope_id; /* Scope ID (new in 2.4) */
};
```

And also that:

> sin6_family is always set to AF_INET6

Why is `sin6_family` required if it's always the same? Is this meant to make transitioning form IPv4 to IPv6 easier because the `struct`s have a similar layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to provide a sort of poor man's polymorphism in the C sockets API, C sockets functions simply take a pointer to a `struct sockaddr *` which will accept an address of potentially many different families.

This relies on the guarantee in C that the address of the first member of a struct is the same as the address of the struct. Since every `sockaddr_*` type's first member is the address family, the internal code can check the family to cast back to the correct address structure.

So, this allows the calls to deduce you've passed an IPv6 address even after casting to a `sockaddr *` and handle it accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

From [the bind man-page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/bind.2.html):

> ```
> int bind(int sockfd, const struct sockaddr *addr, socklen_t addrlen);
> ```
>
> [...]
>   The actual structure passed for the addr argument will depend on the address family.
>   The `sockaddr` structure is defined as something like:
>
> ```
>   struct sockaddr {
>       sa_family_t sa_family;
>       char        sa_data[14];
>   }
> ```
>
> The only purpose of this structure is to cast the structure pointer passed in `addr` in order to avoid compiler warnings.
>   [...]

So you see, `sa_family` is the tag for an implicit extensible [tagged-union](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union) marking the struct as the specialized IPv6-version, instead of the generic unknown, the IPv4 or yet another one.